# RapidShare Regular Expression

Tags: php, regex

Could anyone please help me to find a regular expression for new rapid sharelink

```
http://rapidshare.com/#!download|943dt|421184201|Tools.rar|7316
```

I would like to have something like this one

```
$str = 'blah http://rapidshare.com/#!download|943dt|421184201|Tools.rar|7316 blah';
if(preg_match_all('#http://rapidshare\.com/#!download|(.*?)|([^\s]+)#', $str, $m)) {
    var_dump($m);
}
```

Result

`

```
 array
  0 => 
    array
      0 => string 'http://rapidshare.com/#!download|943dt|421184201|Tools.rar|7316' (length=51)
  1 => 
    array
      0 => string '943dt' (length=5)
  2 => 
    array
      0 => string '421184201' (length=8)

 3 => 
    array
      0 => string 'Tools.rar' (length=8)

 4 => 
    array
      0 => string '7316' (length=8)`
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try this regex:

```
$str = 'blah http://rapidshare.com/#!download|943dt|421184201|Tools.rar|7316 blah';
if(preg_match(
 '@http://rapidshare.com/#!download\|([^\|]+)\|([^\|]+)\|([^\|]+)\|([^\|\s]+)@',
    $str, $m)) {
   var_dump($m);
}

// prints
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(63) "http://rapidshare.com/#!download|943dt|421184201|Tools.rar|7316"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "943dt"
  [2]=>
  string(9) "421184201"
  [3]=>
  string(9) "Tools.rar"
  [4]=>
  string(4) "7316"
}
```

## Update

Wasn't aware of presence of newline characters in the text. If that is the case use below code to remove newline chars first before matching against the regex:

```
preg_match(
 '@http://rapidshare.com/#!download\|([^\|]+)\|([^\|]+)\|([^\|]+)\|([^\|\s]+)@',
    str_replace("\n", "", $str), $m)
```

Comment: It doesn't match all links, nor it will match newlines.

Comment: @webarto: I don't see newline requirement in OP's question. And can you please tell me for which links it won't work? I just have one example link to test it.

Comment: He is obviously trying to build a crawler for warez search engine and he want to crawl forum posts, so newline is a must. You're code is OK.

Comment: @webarto: Had tried @s modifier but it wasn't working for all the cases I tested.

Answer (score 0):

```
@http://rapidshare\.com/#!download|(.*?)|(\d+)|([^\s]+)|(\d+)@
```

Given your example link, that should do it.

Comment: It won't, **#** is a modifier in this case.

Comment: You need to escape those pipes (`|`) if you want to match them literally.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "blah http://rapidshare.com/#!download|943dt|421184201|Tools.rar|7316 blah http://rapidshare.com/#!download|1233dt|123484201|Porn.rar|7232316";
preg_match_all("#http:\/\/rapidshare\.com\/([^\s]+)#is", $string, $matches);

$matches = $matches[0];

foreach($matches as $match){
    $pieces = explode("|", $match);
    unset($pieces[0]);
    $pieces[0] = $match;
    $result[] = $pieces;
}

print_r($result);
```

Result...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => 943dt
            [2] => 421184201
            [3] => Tools.rar
            [4] => 7316
            [0] => http://rapidshare.com/#!download|943dt|421184201|Tools.rar|7316
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1233dt
            [2] => 123484201
            [3] => Porn.rar
            [4] => 7232316
            [0] => http://rapidshare.com/#!download|1233dt|123484201|Porn.rar|7232316
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex is really the wrong tool for this, IMO. You should just use string manipulation to split it on `|` characters, then ignore the first string in the resulting array, which should be `http://rapidshare.com/#!download`. Should be simpler, faster, and easier to debug.